# having issue with NSNotificationDefaultCenter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsnotificationcenter

I have the following code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(cmd:) 
                                                     name:@"cmdAvailable"
                                                   object:nil];
```

and I have the cmd as:

```
-(void) cmd: (NSNotification *) notification
```

in the same UIViewController. On the other UIViewController I have, I did this:

```
 NSDictionary * userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:requestUrl forKey:@"requestUrl"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"cmdAvailable" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

Why is it not calling my `cmd: (NSNotification *) notification` method? I checked and that postNotification is getting called.

Comment: Are you sure the order is correct? That is, the addObserver call is always coming before the notification is posted?

Comment: yes, 100% sure that the order is correct

Comment: How about this: is the receiving view controller still around when the notification is posted? (i.e. it hasn't been deallocated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be this?

```
NSDictionary * userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:requestUrl forKey:@"requestUrl"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"cmdAvailable" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

The documentation says this:

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

> Parameters
>
> - notificationName:
>
>   The name of the notification.
> - notificationSender:
>
>   The object posting the notification.
> - userInfo:
>
>   Information about the the notification. May be nil.

So object should be the object posting the notification, which is `self`

UPDATE

The notification will contain three parts:

> – name
>
> – object
>
> – userInfo

The receiver not only know that the message was sent, but what object sent it.

Comment: You may be right, but the docs don't say that it may be nil. Now I'm curious. I hope he tries it.

Comment: The name and the object parameters have the same use. You might want to get a notification with a certain name, or a notification from an specific object, or a notification with a certain name from a specific object. You should get the notification you are looking for with at least one, the object or the name.